# How to Adjust Angular's URL matching pattern

Tags: regex, angularjs, air, adobe

First things first, I want to adjust the pattern that Angular uses to match against for URL routing. I have found the function and it is running the URL location against these regex(s) found on line 5612 of angular.js (version http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/):

```
SERVER_MATCH = /^([^:]+):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\{?[\w\.-]*\}?)(:([0-9]+))?(\/[^\?#]*)?(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$/,
PATH_MATCH = /^([^\?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$/,
DEFAULT_PORTS = {'http': 80, 'https': 443, 'ftp': 21};
```

So why would I want to do that? I am using angular as the framework for a desktop AIR application. AIR applications can be built using HTML/JS, which is subsequently wrapped in AIR which provides access to the filesystem and OS. So this combination essentially allows you to build a multi-platform desktop web application with angular. Powerful stuff.

Here is the problem AIR has a custom address bar string which looks like `app:/` rather than `http://`. So it has one slash instead of two. Angular uses the the address bar location to route the application, i.e. `http://something.com/#/contactList` means load the `contactList` view and its associated controller.  My knowledge of regex is pretty (very) limited so I can't read the patterns I included above, but I am guessing that the one slash instead of two or something similar to that could be the problem.

My aim is to adjust the patterns so that `app:/` would be a valid pattern and my hope is that the URI segment making and associated actions would still work.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach, I'm still personally feeling like for the most part HTML5 standards (and other little hacks) are providing just about everything you would need via the mobile browsers, but for the sake of anything not available this would be cool to have a work-around.  I'm no Regex expert either but figured could always go the guess and check route.. my first guess is the \/\/ is two escaped forward slashes

Comment: Just to give you the knowledge I'm operating on, backslash I believe is an escape character, w is a "word" + means 0 or 1 of the previous thing, * means 0 1 or many of the previous thing, so basically the SERVER_MATCH shows something that's not a colon followed by a colon, followed by two slashes, then some word, and some dot or slash and maybe more words, then a colon (port number, optional), then it does some stuff to cover the hash it looks like.

Comment: Thanks guys that gives me something to go off. I am thinking of setting the slashes after the colon to at least one rather than exactly 2. I can trial and error it unless someone can confirm?

Comment: This idea kinda reminds me of a project some guys I worked with called Merapi (it was an ActionScript <-> Java bridge).  Would be cool to build this the same way as a generic message bus between the angular code and the AS3 (even better to extend the interface into some AIR module that could be extended to add more Android/iOS functions)... not sure how to properly plan the whole thing but could be very cool

Comment: In this case the project includes very little AS3 as its a Javascript/HTML AIR project, which means you essentially write the whole thing in JS (using whatever libs (ironic) you want). There is an AIR api that exposes some AS3 and OS functionality to JS and then you also compile it as an AIR app. So the bridging isn't necessary per say as its pretty much all JS and even the AS3 can be called from JS like air.someMethod().

Comment: oh wicked, somehow let that one pass me by, thanks for the info I'll have to check that out (does this still work with native extensions "ANEs" too? just in case AIR doesn't have what you want but the target platform does?)

Comment: I think there is the ability to launch native processes if thats what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Mozilla Regular Expressions doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

What @shaunhusain already explained in a comment is mostly correct, except for the following:

- `\w` matches a single alphanumeric character or underscore
- `+`  matches 1 or more (not 0 or 1) of the previous character

Therefore, `\w+` matches a word of length 1 or more characters.

You do need to modify the regex to only have one slash after the colon if you want to match something like `app:/`.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer is correct, here is what the altered Angular code looks like:

```
//** CHANGED REGEX TO MATCH ON 'app:/' as well
var SERVER_MATCH = /^([^:]+):\/+(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\{?[\w\.-]*\}?)(:([0-9]+))?(\/[^\?#]*)?      (\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$/, //var SERVER_MATCH = /^([^:]+):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\{?[\w\.-]*\}?)(:([0-9]+))?(\/[^\?#]*)?(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$/,
```

I found it on line 5612 or thereabouts. Caveat: I have no idea if there will be deleterious side effects of making this change. The general idea was simply to get angular to match on app:/ as it would http:// so that it could function as an Air app.