# AngularJS can't see inner partials and resources in Adobe AIR

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, air

I'm building an Adobe AIR application with AngularJS. And have quickly come across a problem in that Angular can't see partials below a certain level and any `$http` resources.

I've read here: [How to Adjust Angular's URL matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659152/how-to-adjust-angulars-url-matching-pattern) that this is because of the way Angular looks at URLs instead of using app:/ but in 2.0+ it no longer has a SERVER_MATCH so I can't use that regex... if that's even the issue anymore?

Basically if I have a index.html like:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>

<div ng-view></div>

<div ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>
```

It will find those two includes fine! But if in header I have:

```
<div class="header">
    <div ng-include="'partials/header-nav.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Angular **won't** see that `header-nav` in Adobe AIR, because it seems to lose where partials folder is in relation to the rest of the application... *I'd assume that all resources also break for this same reason!*

This also doesn't work:

```
phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
        });
    }]);
```

**Even if I was to call this on the index route**, it won't find the JSON file as the factory doesn't know where to find the file...

Setting `<base href="app:/">` doesn't fix it either but also breaks the links so that's not a solution...

Any ideas? I'm assuming it's something simple...

Comment: Can you prefix with / like '/partials/header-nav.html' ?

Comment: Tried that, but that'd be the same as setting the base href to `app:/` which also doesn't work...

Comment: This will work try this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates . At build time this will inline your template into a JS file and cache it in templateCache upfront.

Comment: That's not going to work for resources or ng-includes.

Comment: `ngInclude` works with `$templateCache` hence the grunt package https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache. The grunt task I mentioned puts things in $templateCache. AIR client on the desktop and any resources - JS and HTML templates are taken care. CSS could be on your top page which you mentioned does not have issues. REST calls will work if the URLs are fully qualified - suggest Restangular where you can specify base URL.

Comment: What about other files that are not necessarily REST calls. This feels like a bit of manual hack to fix an issue elsewhere...

Comment: If you fully qualify other web assets. It should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61377/discussion-between-bhantol-and-cameron).

Answer (score -1):

This sounds more like server issue then angular.

Are you using paths with hashes? If no, try to, maybe bowser is confused by changing the address bar path and relative urls.

Are you using grunt to build the project? It's worth a try, and then you can use [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates) to build them into one js file. There really isn't any reason to make multiple requests for html form you production env.

Comment: There is no server though. It's running inside AIR so it can be used offline.

Answer (score -1):

Load your index.html from the web server.

Then all your resources will be loaded relative to that including the angularJS which will load things like templates.

You can use `StageWebView` as shown below:-

```
    var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 

    public function StageWebViewExample() { 
        webView.stage = this.stage; 
        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight ); 
        webView.loadURL( "http://localhost:9000/app/index.html" ); 
    }
```

Other options are included in my comments to OP's questions but this should serve the solution well in the constraints of the problem defined by OP.